# IE11 doesn't obey jquery mobile's ui-disabled class

Tags: jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-11

I have been using the css class 'ui-disabled' to disable inputs in jquery mobile and it used to work great in all major browsers, but with the release of IE11, noticing that all inputs (except text) including anchor buttons are clickable/changeable even with the class 'ui-disabled'.

I am using jquery mobile's 1.3.2 on windows 7 but apparently the issue occurs on windows 8 machines as well.

Any idea or workaround to fix this issue?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="btn" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Button</a>

<a href="#" id="clickMe" data-role="button">Click Me</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#clickMe').on("click", function(){
  if (!($('#btn').hasClass('ui-disabled'))){
    $('#btn').addClass('ui-disabled');
  }
})

$('#btn').on("click", function(){
 alert("Button was clicked");
})
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Debarupa/6jczxe7m/3/

See how "Button" can be clicked even though it appears disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ui-disabled uses the CSS pointer-events: none which is not well supported in IE.  As a workaround, you could modify your click handler:

```
$('#btn').on("click", function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-disabled')) return false;
    alert("Button was clicked");
})
```